# Cocos2d Messed up Coordinates?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, uistoryboard

I'm new to iOS programming and I followed the tutorial for integrating Storyboarding and Cocos2d posted here

http://www.tinytimgames.com/2012/02/07/cocos2d-and-storyboards/

I followed everything but when I ran my program.  The coordinates were messed up.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jcK7G.jpg

[image]

I have no idea how to fix this =[

Edit:
Here's what it looks like on a blank scene. It looks like part of the scene is just cut off.
[image]

Comment: Search for ios 6 autorotation issue. Cocos2d is in portrait mode.

Comment: still not sure how to fix this

Comment: I tried 
 (BOOL) shouldAutorotate {
    return YES;
}

- (NSUInteger) supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}

but the result is the same